# Connection pool issue without leaks(!?)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I've got an asp.net 4 based web application with connection pool issues.

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached
```

At first I thought there was some connection I forgot to close but it doesn't seem like thats the problem. When I set Pooling=False I can see that all connections are released(by looking in ssms).

Strangely this issue only occurs in our production environment. I tried launching the web application locally and connect it to the production database and then it works fine(releases connections). This makes me think that it has something to do with IIS but I cant figure out what could cause this error. The only difference between the environments is that the application pool is run by NetworkService in dev and an AD-account in prod. Theres no difference in number of users since the site is not launched yet.

I even tried to set Max Pool Size = 10 to provoke the error in our development environment but it still works.

Any ideas?

**Update**

It looks like we've got leaking connections

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.Connection = ConnectionUtil.CreateNewConnection();

      //query code 
}
```

Im guessing the above code only will dispose the SqlCommand but wont close the connection.

Am I right?

Comment: Do you have some long-running threads in the application? It seems that there are some blocking threads, that wait one for the other, and finally a timeout raises. Also - are there any db/table locks in the SQL?

Comment: No, no long running threads. We havent seen any db locks at all. The application has a "player-mode" which causes lots of (small) querys and this raises the connection count to the max pool size(100). It seems like those connections is locked since it takes forever until it possible to get another connection. This doesent happen when the application is running locally and also connection pool count never goes above 20.

Comment: Found the answer. See link below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410222/does-connection-close-when-command-is-disposed-and-the-connection-is-defined-dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to see this error when I forgot to close the connection in the Finally block.

Going back to classic ASP, I used to see "errors" when the default database language was set to English, not database default. (This used to throw an exception that couldn't be caught - at least not in classic ASP)

Comment: That was actually the problem. We were disposing the SqlCommand but not the SqlConnection. Strangely we have never ran it to this problem in our development environment which made it very hard to troubleshoot since we dont have access to the production environment.

Comment: This used to happen to me all the time...be careful and always remember to close your connections in the Finally blocks or you'll wind up with connection zombies. :D